# Numerical Integration of 2nd order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

I need to integrate an equation of the form

$f''(x) g_1+f'(x) g_2=a g_3$

where $a$ is a constant and $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are functions of $x$ 
whose values on the nodes of integration are known. The boundary conditions are 
$f(x=0)=0$, $f(x=1)=f_0$, $f_0$ is a constant. $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are arrays of data, a value for each node.

My question is: should I interpolate $g_1,g_2,g_3$ and then use the NDSolve command, or it is possible to employ directly a numerical tecnique?

Comment: Is this question related to the Software Wolfram Mathematica or more of a question on mathematical / numerical solution methods? If so, then you may want to try http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe that this problem can be solved using Mathematica, so it is relevant with this topic.

Comment: How is *mathematica* supposed to differentiate between `a g3` and `b g4`? There's not enough information here.

Comment: I think the answer is yes, you need to interpolate first if you want to use NDSolve. If you want real help, please provide a minimal working example of the constants, gs and the boundary conditions to solve the problem.

Comment: DK13, to make sure a user is notified, use @MauricioLobos in your reply.  I agree that this is clearly a question about how to use *Mathematica* and like many questions, there is an underlying mathematics issue. -- You could probably set up the finite element method to do this.

Comment: @Feyre , You're right, a g3+b g4 can be written as c g3, g4 is not necessary..

Comment: @tsuresuregusa $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are arrays of data, i.e. they are lists with values for every node.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa  Dirichlet BCs.

Comment: By default `NDSolve` uses an adaptive step size, so how do you know a priori that you have `g` values on the nodes of integration?  Making the `g`s into `InterpolatingFunctions` seems best.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisK . NDSolve can be used only after interpolation. But I thought that I can possibly write an algorithm using finite differences. Any tip for improving interpolation in order to reduce errors?

Comment: @DK13 I wouldn't bother trying to re-invent the `NDSolve`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a finite difference soluton:

```
dx = 1/8;
grid = Range[-1., 1., dx];
g1 = Table[1. + x^2, {x, grid}];
g2 = Table[x, {x, grid}];
g3 = Table[Cos[x], {x, grid}];
a = 2;
unk = Array[f, {Length@grid}];

result = Transpose[{grid,
      unk /. Solve[Join[{unk[[1]] == 0, unk[[-1]] == -2.5},
        Table[
         (f[i + 1] - 2 f[i] + f[i - 1])/dx^2 g1[[i]] + 
           (f[i + 1] - f[i-1])/2/dx g2[[i]] ==  a g3[[i]],
         {i, 2, Length[grid] - 1}]], unk][[1]]}];
ListPlot[result, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

here is a check: `fpp g1 + fp g2` and `a g3` plotted together.

```
fp = Derivative[1][Interpolation[result]]
fpp = Derivative[2][Interpolation[result]]
Show[{
  ListPlot[
   Table[ {grid[[i]], 
     fpp[grid[[i]]] g1[[i]] + fp[grid[[i]]] g2[[i]] }, {i, 
     Length@grid}], Joined -> True],
  ListPlot[Table[ {grid[[i]], a g3[[i]] }, {i, Length@grid}]]}]
```

[image]

note this formulation does not enforce the equation at the ends.

Comment: Thank you! it was really helpful...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a finite element method way:

```
(* data for OP's problem *)
grid = Range[-1., 1., 1./8];
g1 = Table[1. + x^2, {x, grid}];
g2 = Table[x, {x, grid}];
g3 = Table[Cos[x], {x, grid}];

(* solution to OP's problem *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
emesh = ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> List /@ grid,
   "MeshElements" -> {LineElement[Partition[Range@Length@grid, 2, 1]]}];
G1 = Interpolation[Transpose[{grid, g1}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
G2 = Interpolation[Transpose[{grid, g2}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
G3 = Interpolation[Transpose[{grid, g3}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Block[{a = 2},
  {sol} = 
   NDSolve[{f''[x] G1[x] + f'[x] G2[x] == a G3[x], 
     DirichletCondition[f[x] == 0, x == -1]}, 
    f, {x} ∈ emesh]
  ];

(* for comparison *)
Block[{a = 2},
  {sol2} = 
   NDSolve[{f''[x] (1 + x^2) + f'[x] x == a Cos[x], f[-1] == 0, 
     f'[-1] == (f'[-1] /. sol)}, f, {x, -1, 1}]
  ];

Plot[{f[x] /. sol, f[x] /. sol2}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: it is really great, but where is the Dirichlet condition at $x=1$ ??

Comment: @DK13 When I first read your question it didn't have any BCs....I left your original Q on my browser and didn't refresh and see the update until just now. Anyway it's simple enough to add it: `NDSolve[{..., DirichletCondition[f[x] == 0, x == 0], DirichletCondition[f[x] == f0, x == 1]},...]`, isn't it?

Comment: I did it already! Thank you very much!!!! @Michael E2